Is `F a = (a -> p) -> q` an applicative functor?
A type constructor of the form F a = (a -> p) -> q is covariant in a. Here, we assume that p and q are fixed types, not universally quantified, and only a varies. With fixed p and q, we find that F is a functor.
Is F an applicative functor, assuming that p and q are different, inequivalent fixed types?
A specific example is if we set p = Bool and q = Int. Then F a = (a -> Bool) -> Int. Is F applicative?
My guess is that F is not applicative (cannot implement lawful methods pure, zip, ap), for any p and q that are not equivalent and not trivial (that is, not just unit or void types). But I don't have a proof. Neither can I implement the methods of Applicative for F that obey the laws. An example of a non-law-abiding implementation is this:
 zip :: F a -> F b -> F (a, b)
 zip _ _ _ = q0

where q0 is a fixed value of type q. This implementation of zip ignores all its arguments, which loses information and could not possibly obey the identity laws of zip.
Can one prove either that F is applicative or that no lawful methods zip or ap can be implemented for F?
We may assume, if needed, that p and q are monoidal types (I don't think it will help though). We also may assume that further data is given about the types p and q. What is the minimum necessary data?
For instance, to implement pure is the same as to select a value of type F (). The type F () is equivalent to the type p -> q. So, implementing pure means choosing a value of type p -> q. We need to assume that such a value can be chosen (that is, the type p -> q should not be void). What other assumptions are necessary?
As a comparison, if p and q are the same type, we get F a = (a -> p) -> p, which is a continuation monad and is also applicative. So, if the extra data about p and q consists of an isomorphism between p and q then we obtain an applicative F. Is that isomorphism necessary, or can we obtain an applicative F with weaker assumptions than an isomorphism between p and q?

You can't implement pure either, can you (without making assumptions about p and q)?

Correct: if p and q are universally quantified, then there's no pure by parametricity, hence no Applicative. Are you asking for minimal assumptions on p and q so that an instance exists?

@NaïmFavier Let me clarify the question. The types p and q are certainly not universally quantified.

Do you have a type in mind like this one: newtype F p q a = F ((a -> p) -> q). If so, what we said in the comments should apply.

@DavidYoung Consider F a = (a -> Bool) -> Int. Is the functor F applicative? Then we may want to generalize to arbitrary p and q. We might need additional data about p and q. What is that data?

You certainly don't need p and q to be isomorphic: there is an applicative structure whenever q is ().

@NaïmFavier But, if q is () then the entire F a is a constant functor returning (). Another trivial possibility is p = (), in which case q must be a monoid. But this again gives a constant functor. Is there a non-constant applicative F?

Let me rephrase F a = (a -> P) -> Q for clarity on what is quantified. I would also like to sincerely apologize for obnoxiously using Coq to justify my point. My """""proof""""" is strongly reliant on the Curry-Howard isomorphism and I am going to use Coq's proof mode for programming. I am really sorry. So, ekhm,
No
Unless there is a bijection between P and Q, or Q has one value, or P is empty.
If Q has one value then it's trivial, but boring and useless. If P is empty, then F cannot be applied to anything meaningful either.
First of all, I assume we do not fancy bottoms, thus when working with quantified types we are condemned to using only variables given to us contravariantly and external context. As you noticed, pure is not a big deal if we assume existence of some f : P -> Q (otherwise we are lost). The real problem is with <*> (or ap), however.
First, let's assume we have no knowledge about P and Q except that f :: P -> Q. Our problem is expressed in Coq as follows:
Parameters P Q : Type.
Parameter f : P -> Q.

Lemma ap : forall a b,
    (((a -> b) -> P) -> Q) ->
    ((a -> P) -> Q) ->
    ((b -> P) -> Q).

The first two lines introduce our assumptions: existence of some P and Q types and a converting function f. The lemma is essentially a declaration of a type, value of which we are about to look for. The type of the lemma is precisely the type of <*> in Haskell (modulo the newtype constructor).
Let's play a game then.

Proof.
  intros a b Hab Ha fb.

  a : Type
  b : Type
  Hab : ((a -> b) -> P) -> Q
  Ha : (a -> P) -> Q
  fb : b -> P
============================
  Q


The first code snippet is the Coq Ltac proof script. The second is the proof state --- above the line are assumptions (what we "have"), below the line is our goal (what we are looking for, or value of what type we need to find).
We have 3 options to reach Q:

From Hab
From Ha
From f

1: Use Hab
If we want to use Hab, we need to show its premises (aka apply some arguments to it)
Proof.
  intros a b Hab Ha fb.

  apply Hab.

  a : Type
  b : Type
  Hab : ((a -> b) -> P) -> Q
  Ha : (a -> P) -> Q
  fb : b -> P
  ============================
  (a -> b) -> P


The argument is a function. We can assume its argument fa (aka write \fa ->  in Haskell)
Proof.
  intros a b Hab Ha fb.

  apply Hab.
  intros fa.

  a : Type
  b : Type
  Hab : ((a -> b) -> P) -> Q
  Ha : (a -> P) -> Q
  fb : b -> P
  fa : a -> b
  ============================
  P


The only source of P is fb.
Proof.
  intros a b Hab Ha fb.

  apply Hab.
  intros fa.
  apply fb.

  a : Type
  b : Type
  Hab : ((a -> b) -> P) -> Q
  Ha : (a -> P) -> Q
  fb : b -> P
  fa : a -> b
  ============================
  b


The only source of b is fa
Proof.
  intros a b Hab Ha fb.

  apply Hab.
  intros fa.
  apply fb.
  apply fa.

  a : Type
  b : Type
  Hab : ((a -> b) -> P) -> Q
  Ha : (a -> P) -> Q
  fb : b -> P
  fa : a -> b
  ============================
  a


Now we are doomed, because we do not have any value of type a in our hands. Abort.
2. Use Ha
Proof.
  intros a b Hab Ha fb.

  apply Ha.
  intros Haa.

  a : Type
  b : Type
  Hab : ((a -> b) -> P) -> Q
  Ha : (a -> P) -> Q
  fb : b -> P
  ============================
  a -> P


Proof.
  intros a b Hab Ha fb.

  apply Ha.
  intros Haa.

  a : Type
  b : Type
  Hab : ((a -> b) -> P) -> Q
  Ha : (a -> P) -> Q
  fb : b -> P
  Haa : a
  ============================
  P


Proof.
  intros a b Hab Ha fb.

  apply Ha.
  intros Haa.
  apply fb.

  a : Type
  b : Type
  Hab : ((a -> b) -> P) -> Q
  Ha : (a -> P) -> Q
  fb : b -> P
  Haa : a
  ============================
  b


Aaaand it's gone. We have no b.
3. Use f


Proof.
  intros a b Hab Ha fb.

  apply f.

  a : Type
  b : Type
  Hab : ((a -> b) -> P) -> Q
  Ha : (a -> P) -> Q
  fb : b -> P
  ============================
  P


Proof.
  intros a b Hab Ha fb.

  apply f.
  apply fb.

  a : Type
  b : Type
  Hab : ((a -> b) -> P) -> Q
  Ha : (a -> P) -> Q
  fb : b -> P
  ============================
  b

Game over.
But what if we knew something more about P and Q?
The dead end above is really dead only if we completely abstract out P and Q. There were however a few situations where we were asked for a P or Q and could have potentially crafted using some external functions or constructors. Note that we cannot use values of type a or b to externally demand any of those, because those are universally quantified.
Our only chances are either in directly constructing Q or P, or converting g :: Q -> P at some point.
If we decide to fix Q (the result) to any selected value, then, as long as Q has any other value available, pure id <*> might not be an identity. Similar problems arise immediately if you try fixing the solution for P either.
Our last resort is therefore the aforementioned g :: Q -> P. Then, we can reach Q in several ways, one of which is

Definition ap : forall [a b],
    F (a -> b) ->
    F a ->
    F b.

Proof.
  unfold F.
  intros a b Hab Ha fb.

  apply Hab.
  intros fab.
  apply g.
  apply Ha.
  intros Haa.
  apply fb.
  apply fab.
  apply Haa.
Defined.

If that's too ugly, here is the lambda term:
ap = (fun (a b : Type) (Hab : ((a -> b) -> P) -> Q) (Ha : (a -> P) -> Q) (fb : b -> P) =>
 Hab (fun fab : a -> b => g (Ha (fun Haa : a => fb (fab Haa)))))

Or shorter
ap a b Hab Ha fb =
 Hab (fun fab => g (Ha (fun Haa => fb (fab Haa)))))

Now, remember that pure used f? If we simplify the law of identity for this case, we reduce (with functional extensionality in mind) to something of form
Lemma law_ident : forall a (v : F a), ap (pure (fun x => x)) v = v.
  unfold F, ap, pure.
  intros.
  extensionality x. (* Functions are equal, if they are equal on any argument x *)
  replace (fun Haa => x Haa) with x by (extensionality y; auto).

  a : Type
  v : (a -> P) -> Q
  x : a -> P
  ============================
  f (g (v x)) = v x

Which is to say that g is an injection. If we try other laws, we inevitably end up needing the opposite --- that f is an injection too. That boils down to saying that P and Q are isomorphic, so technically F is equivalent to F' a = (a -> Q) -> Q, which is an applicative functor perfectly fine.
Of course, this is not a proof, but a vague picture of what happens if you try to look for a solution. ap can be expressed in other configurations, but sooner or later you will end up with the same issues. An actual proof would be more convoluted, but I hope my coqhandwaving will suffice since we are on StackOverflow, not on Theoretical Computer Science SE or Math SE.

What if P = 2 and Q = 3 (the types with 2 and 3 distinct values respectively). Can we write down some specific implementations of pure and ap that satisfy the laws? Or if P = Bool and Q = Int or vice versa?

Your approach seems to be based on an assumption that some functions f : P → Q and g : Q → P are given. Indeed, one can then implement the applicative methods and derive the laws for f and g. The laws force f and g to be mutually inverse bijections. But the assumption of having f and g can be weakened: suppose we are given f : P → Q and h : ((((P → P) → Q) → P) → Q) → Q. (How did I come up with that abomination? I could explain.) Then we can still implement pure and ap. It remains to see what laws f and h must satisfy. Perhaps you can do that with Coq?

I guess that should be possible to formally prove, though it's generally tough to prove non-existence of things, and especially tough when the domain are functions. I tried to make a more well-formed argument and back it with some Coq gibber, but that turned to be very cumbersome, at least with constructive approach. If you feel my argument is dissatisfying, I can remove my post so, but if I were you I would ask then on CS stack exchange or even math SE.
I suppose that h is not completely arbitrary, what is its relation to f?

I'd rather keep the answers. I don't know how to rove this easily. I don't expect anyone to answer this, really.
